# I study Three js, I just can’t figure out what the problem is. The console gives an error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')"

Tags: javascript

> Blockquote         I study Three js, I just can’t figure out what the problem is. The console gives
> an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'length')
> at window.onload"

```
window.onload = () => {
    let width = window.innerWidth
    let height = window.innerHeight
     const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')

  canvas.setAttribute('width', width)
  canvas.setAttribute('height', height)

  let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvas });
  renderer.setClearColor(0x000000)

  let scene = new THREE.Scene();

  let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 0.1, 5000);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 1000)

  let light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff)
  scene.add(light)

  const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(200, 12, 12)
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00, vertexColors:
```

THREE.FaceColors });

```
// console.log(geometry);

for (var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i++) {
    geometry.faces[i].color.setRGB(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random())
}

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
scene.add(mesh)

const loop = () => {
    mesh.rotation.y -= Math.PI / 500;

    renderer.render(scene, camera)
    requestAnimationFrame(() => { loop() })
}

loop()
```

}

Comment: I don't think .face is a property of SphereGeometry class _https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/SphereGeometry_ or the underlying BufferGeometry class _https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry_.  Do a quick search in both of these docs for .face.  Your for loop relies on this property for initialization and also tries to manipulate it.

Comment: I just watched video tutorials on youtube where everything was done exactly the same as in my code, but everything worked for him, I have an error

Comment: what's the link to that?

Comment: https://youtu.be/ngGQD7mIEok this video